# Access a particular line from a LOAD DATA INFILE MySQL script

Tags: mysql, text, import

I want to load a (big) data file into a MySQL database. For efficiency, I'm trying to use the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). My data is like so (fields all have fixed sizes, and the date is in the yyyy-MM-dd format):

```
date
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
...
```

and i want to get them like this in the database like this

```
some_id || field1 || field2 || field3 || date
```

How could I access the date from the first row (efficiently if possible) and putting it in all rows? I know how to get the other fields.
Thanks

Comment: you have 2 questions here, no?

Comment: and the way you represented `date` in your text file is ambiguous. Please clear that up.

Comment: @Drew is it clear after my EDIT

Comment: load data infile works off all the row data on one row of text going into one row in a table. (Well it can skip some data but still) How is the above compatible with that. Maybe I am dense

Comment: So your job is to prep the data output into the CSV (or morphed up one like yours) such that that can happen. Otherwise you need a programming language other than mysql's to loop and do custom stuff, which will be tremendously slower.

Comment: Well, the programing language can determine the date using data from the 1st row, then load data infile can be called with date as a parameter and skipping the 1st line.

Comment: @Shadow Using a programming langage will be, I think, slower. That's why I would like a way to do it directly with a script if possible (MySQL is not mandatory but I'd like an open source solution)

Comment: What's the difference between a programming language and the script? And what's got all these to do with being an open source solution? I'm sorry, but I can't follow you.

Comment: Using an programming langage will (I believe) take a much much longer time than using a DB script. The second fact is that I'm not attached to MySQL.I can change my DBMS if it can help (though I prefer it to be open sourced so not SQL-server and others) but you can forget about this last point.